# Typing in a windows phone textbox stops while calling a web service

Tags: c#, web-services, xaml, windows-phone-8, textbox

I have a textbox in which the user types something. Once there are 3 characters, a method is called to get information from a web service, and typing is not fluent.
I think the problem is that until information is not received, it's imposible to type anything.

My textbox XAML:

```
  <toolkit:PhoneTextBox Background="Black" Width="460" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="1" Padding="0" BorderBrush="White"  x:Name="searchtextbox" TextWrapping="Wrap" Hint="Buscar" AcceptsReturn="True" FontSize="21.333" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight" Foreground="White" ActionIcon="/Assets/images/appbar/feature.search.png" InputScope="AddressCity" TextChanged="searchtextbox_TextChanged" SelectionForeground="White" CaretBrush="White" LostFocus="searchtextbox_LostFocus" GotFocus="searchtextbox_GotFocus" Height="71" MaxHeight="71" />
```

I use textchanged method to capture the info.

```
 private async void searchtextbox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ListaResultados.ItemsSource = await Protos.getProtoBusqueda(this.searchtextbox.Text);

        }
```

And this is the method which calls the WS:

```
public static async Task<ObservableCollection<Resultados> getProtoBusqueda(string txtCajaBusqueda)
        {

            string txtBusqueda = txtCajaBusqueda;


            string url = String.Concat(urlBasic, urlBusqueda, txtBusqueda, format);
            App.resultados.Coordenadas = null;

            try
            {

                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);

                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(String.Format(url));

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        Stream data = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();                           
                        UserSearchEntityV2 datos = UserSearchEntityV2.ParseFrom(data);

                       //HIDDEN CODE TO SET INFORMATION//   

                            ListOfResults.Add(new Resultados() { Nombre = datos.ResultList[i].Name, Municipio = datos.ResultList[i].Mun, Provincia = bbdd.obtenerProvincia(datos.ResultList[i].Prov), Id = datos.ResultList[i].Id, Tipo = datos.ResultList[i].Type, TipoImagen = imagenTipo, Transporte1 = listaTransportes[0], Transporte2 = listaTransportes[1], Transporte3 = listaTransportes[2], Transporte4 = listaTransportes[3], Transporte5 = listaTransportes[4], Transporte6 = listaTransportes[5], Transporte7 = listaTransportes[6], Transporte8 = listaTransportes[7], IsStop = isStop });

                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("No se ha podido conectar");

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            return ListOfResults;

        }
```

Both methods are asynchronous, so, I don't understand why typing is so slow.
Thanks!

Comment: It could also come from all the code surrounding your async calls to HttpClient. You should leave only the HTTP calls (returning a dummy empty list) and see if it's still slow. Make especially sure to remove the call to `UserSearchEntityV2.ParseFrom`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is when you assign the  this.ListaResultados.ItemsSource from the result, it can be 3 times in milliseconds and that is getting crazy the UI.

Do not assign any result from the operation to be sure it's not lacking, just call the method without assign it to the ItemsSource.

To assign correctly the ItemsSource would be better if you create a viewmodel with INotifyPropertyChanged and bind it to the ItemsSource, it will manage it better